# Google Chrome does not preload itself on boot in Windows 11 and does not run in background

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11

I noticed that Google Chrome does not start on boot in Windows 11 nor does it stay running in background when all browser windows are closed. As a result, opening the first browser window happens with a noticeable lag.

I tried playing with the registry key that Chrome uses to start itself on boot, but no results. Chrome seems to remove its own registry value in Windows 11. The below entry would pre-load Chrome successfully on boot in Win'10, but has no effect in Win'11. In fact, Chrome will start, but will delete this line from registry and will shutdown.

```
> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
    > GoogleChromeAutoLaunch_D9C6B67A63EF2C294D4A204374B6A795
        "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-startup-window /prefetch:5
```

I replicated this behavior on a laptop and in VM, clean Win'11 install in both cases.

Does anyone else observe the same behavior of Chrome in Windows 11? How to make Chrome auto-start on boot? Is this a bug? Is this intentional?

Comment: Did you try Task Manager, Startup Tab and use that to load Chrome?

Comment: The Startup tab is managed by the registry key that I was tinkering with. There is no Chrome in the Startup Tab in Win'11 Task Manager because there is no corresponding registry entry. I tried reinstalling Chrome, but no effect.

Comment: Try:   Click the Google Chrome folder to expand it, then click the Google Chrome icon and drag it down to the Startup folder.    (found in a search).   I do not start Browser at Windows Startup.

Comment: This solution will work, but it will show a Chrome browser window on boot, and the process will terminate once the window is closed. On Windows, Chrome pre-loads itself on boot without showing a window, done so to hot-start the process in the background, in order to open browser windows faster. I'm looking to achieve such behavior, which seems broken on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer. Chrome only loads itself on boot if there are any extensions install that require it to remain "resident" in memory. With no extensions installed, Chrome cold-boots every time we click its icon on a desktop, which adds another ~0.3 seconds for its window to appear.
I found an extension called [Lightning Reopen](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/lightning-reopen/ahphokgmcecbjeipkfkamcdmemghkaph?pli=1) that does just that: it's an empty extension that simply forces Chrome to remain in the memory and makes Chrome window start instantly.